# Undefined Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Icon')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I've been playing around with NextJS and TypeScript by watching a few videos and going through tutorials online. Until recently I have not run in to an issue, but am stuck on this. I've gone through my `type.ts`, `resumeData.ts`, and my `Bar.tsx` and my vsCode is not giving me any problem errors (of course I'm aware that it does not pick up everything).

I had no issue with the name, and level but for some reason seem to be missing why I am getting an undefined error in my `Bar.tsx` inside `const Bar:...` (besides the obvious of it saying it is not defined) and am unsure even where it should be defined or how.

I have gone ahead and posted each of the above mentioned files below.

Thanks for any help or suggestions on this.

**Bar.tsx**

```
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { ISkill } from "../type";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Bar: FunctionComponent<{ value: ISkill }> = ({
  value: { Icon, name, level },
}) => {
  const bar_width = `${level}%`;

  const variants = {
    initial: {
      width: 0,
    },
    animate: {
      width: bar_width,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.4,
        type: "spring",
        damping: 10,
        stiffness: 100,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="my-2 text-white bg-gray-300 rounded-full dark:bg-dark-300 dark:bg-black-500">
      <motion.div
        className="flex items-center px-4 py-1 rounded-full bg-gradient-to-r from-green to-blue-600"
        style={{ width: bar_width }}
        variants={variants}
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
      >
        <Icon className="mr-3" />
        {name}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Bar;
```

**type.ts**

```
import { IconType } from "react-icons/lib";

export interface IService {
  Icon: IconType;
  title: string;
  about: string;
}

export interface ISkill {
  Icon: IconType;
  name: string;
  level: string;
}

export interface IProject {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  image_path: string;
  deployed_url: string;
  github_url: string;
  category: Category[];
  key_techs: string[];
}

export type Category = "react" | "mongo" | "express" | "django" | "node";
```

**resumeData.ts**

```
import { ISkill } from "../type";
import { BsCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";

export const languages: ISkill[] = [
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "Python",
    level: "70%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "JavaScript",
    level: "60%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "React Native",
    level: "80%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "React",
    level: "70%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "Django",
    level: "80%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "Bootstrap",
    level: "80%",
  },
];

export const tools: ISkill[] = [
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "Figma",
    level: "85%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "Photoshop",
    level: "45%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "Illustrator",
    level: "60%",
  },
  {
    Icon: BsCircleFill,
    name: "Framer",
    level: "70%",
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you show us the `<Bar ... />` part of the parent's JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Bar: FunctionComponent<{ value: ISkill }> = ({
  value: { Icon, name, level },
}) => {
// Your code ...
}
```

Here the error is coming from line 2: `value: {Icon, name, level}`.
The `value` coming via props seems to be undefined. Check where the `Bar` component is used and if the `props` are passed properly.

Example:

```
<Bar value={{Icon: YourIcon, name: "...", level: "..."}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks nightElf

Looks like the simplest solution of going back a bit further helped. It would seem a pathing did not get properly refactored which was causing the issue. Now I just feel silly for not looking that extra step backwards.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a possibility that `Icon` is undefined, you can always test for its value before attempting to include it in your JSX. This should at least eliminate the error.

```
{Icon && (<Icon className="mr-3" />)}
```

To determine why `Icon` is undefined in the first place, you have to look at the parent component that's including `<Bar>` to see where the `Icon` property is not properly being set in the `value` object.